# Is it possible to create a UTM file for one architecture (say ARM) and convert it to another (say Intel)?

Tags: virtualization

*Host machine:*  Apple M2 Silicon ARM architecture running Mac OS Ventura

*Guest machine:* Apple M2 Silicon ARM architecture running Mac OS Ventura

*Used* [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/).

Under the hood, there is a *.utm file created that saves the state of the guest OS.  If I install any software / create files, it will all be saved in that underlying *.utm file.  Then later on, I can decide to distribute this *.utm file to another ARM-based host, where they can import it and get all my changes and software I installed.

**Question**: Can an Intel-based host import this ARM-based guest *.utm file? Or would I have to separately / independently repeat the entire process I did on an Intel host and create a brand new *.utm file for Intel-hosts ?

**Related question** : given an ARM-based guest *.utm file, is it possible to "convert" it to another architecture (i.e. can we convert from ARM-based *.utm ---> Intel-based *.utm)?

Comment: You would have to repeat it - one reason is that the virtualisation mechanism is totally different for Intel and Arm on an Arm machine